# Complex moment problem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a complex-valued random variable.  For simplicity, let us assume that $X$ is bounded.  If I know all of the $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ then do I know the distribution of $X$?  I know it suffices to know all $\mathbb{E}[X^k\overline{X^l}]$.  What restrictions on $X$ might ensure that you only need to know the nonconjugate moments?

My efforts here are that I know that there is a nonzero complex linear functional annihilating all holomorphic functions.  Trouble is I need a real linear functional.

Comment: Could you reformulate the problem in terms of a linear functional on the algebra of polynomials? E.g. as follows. *Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb C$ with compact support and $\varphi:\mathbb C[z,\overline z]\to\mathbb C$ be the linear functional defined  by integration w.r.t. $\mu$. Then $\mu$ is uniquely defined by the moments $\varphi(z^k),\ k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$.* This would be a kind of truncated moment problem. What do you mean by real functional?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk I mean (equivalently) that it takes real functions to real functions, or that it is represented by a signed measure.  I don't see why you call it truncated?  It is not as if we are dealing with truncated random variables.  Is it truncated because the information available is truncated just to nonconjugate moments?

Comment: Truncated moment problem is a standard notion. It means that not all moments (usually only finitely many) of the measure are given. As for your question, consider the positive (normalized) measure $\mu_r$ on the circle $\mathbb T_r=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon|z|=r\}$ for some $r>0$ and let $\varphi_r$ be the linear functional on $\mathbb C[z,\overline z]$ given by integration w.r.t. $\mu_r$. Then $\varphi_r(1)=1$ and $\varphi(z^k)=0$ for every $r>0$. That is, you cannot recover the measure on $\mathbb C $ if only nonconjugate moments are given.

Comment: Even if you know the distribution of $\mathbb{E}[X^k\bar{X}^l]$ you may not know the distribution of $X$, it means that we can get an infinit number of distribution with the same moments, this case is called indeterminate moment problem and it appear since the support of the low is non-bounded.

Answer (score 0):

(Caution: This is not a complete solution.)

First, consider an even simpler case where the support of $X$ is a finite set of points. Say the support is $\{z_1, z_2, ..., z_n\}$. Then the question of determinacy of $X$ from $\{\mathbb{E}[X^k]\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is equivalent to asking if the infinite-dimensional vectors $(1, z_i, z_i^2, ...)$ are linear independent.

The last statement is true, and to see the linear independence, it is sufficient to look at the first $n+1$ coordinates, $(1, z_i, z_i^2, ..., z_i^n)$. (If they are dependent, then it means that there is a $n$-th degree polynomial with $n+1$ distinct root, which is false.)

So, in this simple case, $X$ is determined by $\{\mathbb{E}[X^k]\}_{k=0}^\infty$. This suggests that the general case is also determined (assuming boundedness etc). One can potentially use $\epsilon$-net arguments to bridge the gap.